# My SQL Error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, dreamweaver

I have a MySQL database in a 3rd party server. I am trying to access it from my local machine using PHP in Dreamweaver. However, I am getting the following error:

> MySQL Error #2002:
> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
> after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host
> failed to respond.

Thank you.

Comment: What does "in Dreamweaver" mean?  Are you coding in dreamweaver, or trying to make the connection through Dreamweaver?

Comment: Can you show us how you make the connection ?

Comment: @rockerst I am using dreamweaver for development.

Comment: @Warface I am using the database tab in dreamweaver to connect to the db in php. It asks for the server name, username and password.

Comment: It should ask for the database name too no ?!?

Comment: yeah ut did. and i typed it correctly

Comment: wow, if you're just starting programming, DO NOT START WITH PHP. Why? You will start off with really BAD habits. The more restrictive a programming language is, the better it is for a beginner. I recommend you to start with Ada, it will force you to start with good habits. There's an Ada web server so you can still make web sites/apps with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means you can't connect to the server. Check your connecting to the correct IP address and your firewall is configured to allow traffic.

Comment: This should be a comment rather an answer

Comment: @Rahul Why? It gives what i think the problem is and one way of solving it.

Comment: Try telneting to that address ( telnet ip port (default 3306))

Comment: Yes type that in command prompt. You may need to install telnet http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Telnet-frequently-asked-questions

Comment: @TomSquires It doesn't help me. I am getting return packets from my destination IP and I configured my firewall to allow traffic still it shows me .." A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

Answer (score 2):

If your using "localhost" also try host name as 127.0.0.1. If its server try from mysql terminal whether that host is connecting from your local machine.

In local machine I have faced same issue with host localhost and changed to 127.0.0.1 then its works well.