# remote database error in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, remote-access

I am getting error while i configure remote database in phpMyadmin.
error is like as below

> #2002 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond.

The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

Comment: A probable repeat

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818104/my-sql-error-a-connection-attempt-failed-because-the-connected-party-did-not-pr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your MySQL server does not accept connections from external hosts. Unless you are the administrator of the server, you most likely cannot change this.