# Laravel application not connecting to MySQL in App in azure

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, azure

I have created Web App + MySQL resource. Deployed laravel application from bitbucket and it is working good. Now I need to link the database. So I have imported my local DB through MySQL in App. But I'm stuck how to configure.

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I'm getting the above error if I try to login.

Below is the .env file

```
APP_NAME=SMS
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=<App key>
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=<Application URL>

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=49226
DB_DATABASE=localdb
DB_USERNAME=azure
DB_PASSWORD=<Password>
```

Comment: Have you configured the [firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-firewall-rules#connecting-from-azure)

Comment: No.. how to do that please

Comment: Please see the link in my above comment.

Comment: Does it work if configure the firewall?

Comment: The link you mentioned says to go to Connection security pane, which is not present in my portal :(

Comment: @IvanYang is there any workaround? I'm stuck with this problem from the past few days...

Comment: not sure why you don't have this pane, can you try use azure cli to configure the firewall? Follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-firewall-rules#programmatically-managing-firewall-rules). If it does not work, I have no idea :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For APP_ENV replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 in .env file.
This will solve the issue.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39993447/4468757